# upload a file as part of the Body with Web API2

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, mime-types

I want to create WebAPI POST request which gets the body and save it in Database.
One of the body's fields is a ***file***, which can be the image, pdf, ...

should I create a **Async Post request** and post the file to that?
This is the sample I found for that.
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/uploading-files-asynchronously-using-asp.net-web-api.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 'HttpPostedFileBase' class to post the file as part of the Http request Body.
Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  // you API code
}
```

Comment: I cant have a model passed as FromBody  in this case. actually I cant use it with Web API